# Is there a sure shot way of telling whether a reaction is cis addition or trans addition?

Tags: organic-chemistry

For example we say Hydrogenation in cis addition , by looking at a reaction and analyzing can we say whether it’s cis/trans addition? Or Is it purely on the basis of experiments we say it’s cis/trans

Comment: What do you mean by looking at the reaction?

Comment: Like I give you a reaction and you can tell me whether it’s cis or trans addition

Comment: That's exactly the problem. What does that mean? You provide the mechanism? The products? The name of the reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there cannot be a way in which you can always say whether a reaction is cis- addition or trans- addition just by looking at the reaction unless you know its mechanism or the fact itself and mechanism is proposed using the experimental facts. So experiment is the ultimate source.